# Importing CA signed p7b file into KDB?

Tags: tls

We created a certificate signing request using IBM GSKit. The CA is using Microsoft CA server. I downloaded the signed cert complete with chain information. The format is PCKS#7 with an extension of p7b.

GSKit cannot import the P7B format (Binary or Base 64). The .cer file issued by the CA server do not contain the CA certificate and hence cannot be used. Using OpenSSL, I converted the PCKS #7 file into a .cer file. This unfortunately produces a file that has no CA certificate.

The command was a follow: penssl pkcs7 -inform der -in h:\der.p7b -print_certs -out h:\a.cer

Can I import the signed .cer into the kdb file and then import the CA certificate into the same KDB to complete it?

Or is that a way to convert the p7b file into a format with both server and CA cert intack?

Comment: If the p7b contains a chain of certs, `openssl pkcs7 -print_certs` puts ALL of them in the output file, each in PEM. If you look with any text editor or tool you should see them. However most tools that _read_ a PEM cert (not a P7 or P12 etc) read only _one_ cert, so the subsequent certs are ignored. You can split the file into separate files manually with a text editor or automatically by something like `awk 'BEGIN{n=0;f="file"n} {print>f} /-----END/{close(f); f="file"(++n);}'`. But I don't know anything about GSKit and don't know what you can or should give it.

Comment: Let me get this correctly, Are you saying that the openssl pkcs7 -print_certs will put the cers into one PEM file. I had previously use Java keytool and it doesn't have an issue with P7b. Alternatively, I intend to expert each certificate individually and add them to the KDB files.

Comment: If there are multiple certs in the pk7b it will put them all in the output yes -- as I said, **look in the file** -- but a file containing multiple separate certs in PEM may not be usable. Java `keytool` can read either a p7b _or_ a 'bare' sequence of certs (like this) as the 'reply' chain _for a privatekey_ (but _not_ as multiple trusted certs); the other software you refer to might not.